# How should I reference an element created in React-Typescript and change its CSS properties?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-typescript

I have a form which needs its css Display to be set to block when I click on a certain button. When I click on the Add button id="add" it should set the css style block for id="modalContent" div.
I've just started react and am completely new to it. I read something about ref but couldn't completely understand how to go through with it.

**AddFormMod.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';
    import './App.css';
    
    
    function AddForm(){
        return (
            <div id="modalContent" className="modal-content">
                <h1 id="headerAdd">ADD NEW CONTACT</h1>
                <form action="#" id="myForm">
                    <label className="required label"  ><b>Name: </b></label><br />
                    <input className="form-fields type1" type="text" id="name" name="name" required></input><br/><br/>
                    <label className="required label"  ><b>Email:</b> </label><br/>
                    <input className="form-fields type1 " type="email" id="email" name="mail" required></input><br/><br/>
                    <label className="required label"  ><b>Mobile:</b> </label>
                    <label className="label" id="landlinelabel"  ><b>Landline:</b></label><br/>
                    <input className="form-fields" type="tel" id="mobile" name="mobile" pattern="^\d{10}$" required></input>
                    <input className="form-fields" type="tel" id="landline" name="landline" ></input><br/><br/>
                    <label className="label"  ><b>Website</b></label><br/>
                    <input className="form-fields type1" type="text" id="website" name="website" ></input><br/><br/>
                    <label className="label"><b>Address:</b> </label><br/>
                    <textarea className="addressstyle form-fields" id="address1" name="address1" rows={9} cols={74}></textarea>
                    <input className = "buttonstyle" type="submit" value="Add" id="adddetails" ></input>
                    <input className = "buttonstyle" type="button" value="Cancel" id="candetails"></input>
                </form> 
            </div>
            
        );
    }
    
    export default AddForm;
```

**App.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import AddForm from './AddFormMod';



function App() {
  return (
    <p id="title"> Address Book </p>
  );
}

function AddHome(){
  return (
      <div>
          <button id="home" >HOME</button>
          <button id="add" onClick={} >+ADD</button>
      </div>
  );
}

function ContactBar(){

  return (
    <div>
      <p id="contacts">CONTACTS</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export { App , AddHome, ContactBar };
```

Comment: Check with your browser. See the rendered code. If you can create a demo out of your code, I can help.

Comment: You do not need or want refs.  @JAM's answer is correct.  You can also pass props to the `AddForm` component when you call it.  `<AddForm someProp="something"/>`.  Right now it takes no props, but it could use props to control the class names or the styles.

Answer (score 1):

One approach to achieve the result you want, is to utilize [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html). For example, when you click the "add"-button in your `AddHome` component, you can set a state variable to render the `AddForm`-component:

```
function AddHome(){
  const [shouldRenderForm, setShouldRenderForm] = useState(false);
  return (
      <div>
          <button id="home" >HOME</button>
          <button id="add" onClick={() => setShouldRenderForm(true)} >+ADD</button>
          {shouldRenderForm && <AddForm />}
      </div>
  );
}
```

I'm also guessing you want to "close the form" after submit or via a close button inside the `AddForm`-component.  To achieve this, simply pass a prop to the component, for the `AddForm`-component to call  to close the form:

```
// ... in the add AddHome component:
{shouldRenderForm && <AddForm closeForm={() => setShouldRenderForm(false)} />}

// ... in AddForm component:
type AddFormProps = { closeForm: () => void };
function AddForm({ closeForm }: AddFormProps) {
  // ... i.e. on a button to close the form
  <button type="button" onClick={() => closeForm()}>Cancel</button>
}
```

Checkout a working example in [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/long-sea-7z0du?file=/src/App.tsx).